# Method to determine all elements of a given order.

Tags: number-theory

how do i determine all the positive integers $b$ such that $ord_{341}(b)=35$ on thing is that b should be a multiple of either 11 or 31  otherwise the CRT implys that b has order 30 or less... other than that im not sure how to find all of them. i mean theres about 30 multiples of 11 in there and about 10 multiples of 31 that alot of things to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b$ is a multiple of $11$, you have $b^k\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$  (unless $k=0$); you cannot have $b^k\equiv 1\pmod{11\cdot 31}$, since that would give you an impossible congruence modulo $11$. Of course, the same is true if $b$ is a multiple of $31$.

The conclusion is that $b$ must NOT be a multiple of $11$ or $31$, and $\gcd(b,341)=1$.

Now, the multplicative group $\mathrm{U}(341)$ has order $\phi(341)=30$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element must be a divisor of $30$, and cannot be $35$.